# Google Maps search through my markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, search, google-maps-api-3

So I have two markers placed (will be more) and I have a search bar overtop of my map. I would like to be able to use this search bar to search keywords and have the map center on the marker with those keywords. I'm assuming I would do something along the lines of adding custom tags to my markers that would act as the keywords, but I am unsure how this would work since I am creating my markers in a for loop. I don't really know how to start implementing something like this. But here is my code to work with:

```
var locations = [
            ['Passage Island', 49.343085, -123.305938, 'http://tylerkohlhaas.github.io/waterscout/passage.html'],
            ['Point Atkinson', 49.329925, -123.264994, 'http://tylerkohlhaas.github.io/waterscout/patkinson.html']
        ];
var i;

        for(i=0; i < locations.length; i++)
        {
            var markers = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]), 
                map: map,
                clickable: true,
                url: locations[i][3],
                zIndex: 1
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'click', function(){
                window.location.href = this.url; 
            });
        }
```

And the html for my search bar is very basic:

```
<form>
            <input type="search", class="SearchBar", placeholder="Search for an area", name="Search", target="_self", size=50>
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

```
var locations = [
        ['Passage Island', 49.343085, -123.305938, 'http://tylerkohlhaas.github.io/waterscout/passage.html',['tag1','tag2']],
        ['Point Atkinson', 49.329925, -123.264994, 'http://tylerkohlhaas.github.io/waterscout/patkinson.html',['tag3','tag4']]
    ];
    var i;
    var markerArray=[];

    for(i=0; i < locations.length; i++)
    {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]), 
            map: map,
            clickable: true,
            url: locations[i][3],
            zIndex: 1,
            searchTag: locations[i][4],
            searchName: locations[i][0]
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            window.location.href = this.url; 
        });
        markerArray.push(marker);
    }
```

And in your search function you'll use searchTag and searchName fields in markerArray. I.E. if you wants to look into the first marker you'll use something like `markerArray[0]['searchTag']`